# std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for fails immediately

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

I'm using a `std::timed_mutex` for the first time and it's not behaving the way I expect. It appears to fail immediately instead of waiting for the mutex. I'm providing the lock timeout in milliseconds (as shown here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/timed_mutex/try_lock_for/). But the call to `try_lock_for()` fails right away.

Here's the class that handles locking and unlocking the mutex:

```
  const unsigned int DEFAULT_MUTEX_WAIT_TIME_MS = 5 * 60 * 1000;

  class ScopedTimedMutexLock
  {
  public:
     ScopedTimedMutexLock(std::timed_mutex* sourceMutex, unsigned int numWaitMilliseconds=DEFAULT_MUTEX_WAIT_TIME_MS)
        m_mutex(sourceMutex)
     {
        if( !m_mutex->try_lock_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(numWaitMilliseconds) ) )
        {
           std::string message = "Timeout attempting to acquire mutex lock for ";
           message += Conversion::toString(numWaitMilliseconds);
           message += "ms";
           throw MutexException(message);
        }
     }
     ~ScopedTimedMutexLock()
     {
        m_mutex->unlock();
     }
  private:
     std::timed_mutex* m_mutex;
  };
```

And this is where it's being used:

```
  void  CommandService::Process( RequestType& request )
  {
     unsigned long callTime =
        std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(
           std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
        ).count();

     try
     {
        ScopedTimedMutexLock lock( m_classMutex, request.getLockWaitTimeMs(DEFAULT_MUTEX_WAIT_TIME_MS) );
        // ... command processing code goes here
     }
     catch( MutexException& mutexException )
     {
        unsigned long catchTime =
           std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(
              std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
           ).count();
        cout << "The following error occured while attempting to process command"
             << "\n   call  time: " << callTime
             << "\n   catch time: " << catchTime;
        cout << mutexException.description();
     }
  }
```

Here's the console output:

```
The following error occured while attempting to process command
   call  time: 1131268914
   catch time: 1131268914
Timeout attempting to acquire mutex lock for 300000ms
```

Any idea where this is going wrong? Is the conversion to `std::chrono::milliseconds` correct? How do I make `try_lock_for()` wait for the lock?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** The call to `try_lock_for()` didn't **always** fail immediately. Many times the call acquired the lock and everything worked as expected. The failures I was seeing were intermittent. See my answer below for details about why this was failing.

Comment: the link you give refers to `std::unique_lock::try_lock_for` but you use `std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for`. Btw, there is also `std::to_string`, no need to have your own `Conversion::toString` for simple builtin types.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a MVCE (by purging any unnecessary code and providing a working `main()`)?

Comment: Yes, your code seems very complex when your only claim is that try lock for aborts early.  You have exceptions, pointers, custom classes, all of it is noise: to determine if your claim is correct, you are asking us to first debug or verify a pile of your code.  [MCVE] are required when you ask "why isn't this code working", and the above is not minimal nor complete.

Comment: My guess would be undefined behavior somewhere in the code not shown. E.g. `*m_classMutex` is already owned by the thread making the call; or `m_classMutex` is a dangling pointer to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of the problem is mentioned in the description for `try_lock_for()` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex/try_lock_for. Near the end of the description it says:

> As with try_lock(), this function is allowed to fail spuriously and
>   return false even if the mutex was not locked by any other thread at
>   some point during timeout_duration.

I naively assumed there were only two possible outcomes: (1) the function acquires the lock within the time period, or (2) the function fails after the wait time has elapsed. But there is another possibility, (3) the function fails after a relatively short time for no specified reason. TL;DR, my bad.

I solved the problem by rewriting the `ScopedTimedMutexLock` constructor to loop on `try_lock()` until the lock is acquired or the wait time limit is exceeded.

```
 ScopedTimedMutexLock(std::timed_mutex* sourceMutex, unsigned int numWaitMilliseconds=DEFAULT_MUTEX_WAIT_TIME_MS)
    m_mutex(sourceMutex)
 {
    const unsigned SLEEP_TIME_MS = 5;
    bool isLocked = false;
    unsigned long startMS = now();
    while( now() - startMS < numWaitMilliseconds && !isLocked )
    {
       isLocked = m_sourceMutex->try_lock();
       if( !isLocked )
       {
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(
              std::chrono::milliseconds(SLEEP_TIME_MS));
       }
    }
    if( !isLocked )
    {
       std::string message = "Timeout attempting to acquire mutex lock for ";
       message += Conversion::toString(numWaitMilliseconds);
       message += "ms";
       throw MutexException(message);
    }
 }
```

Where `now()` is defined like this:

```
  private:
     unsigned long now() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() ).count();
     }
```

Comment: Does it always fail spuriously right away or only sometimes?  I'd expect spurious failures to pretty much only occur when there's contention or signals happening. Maybe some other times, but not every use of the function.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `try_lock_for()` was failing intermittently.

Comment: That sounds more like what I would expect. However it appears that the spurious failure you're seeing is an implementation bug. The C++11/14 standards say this about `timed_mutex::try_lock_for()` (emphasis added): "The function shall return within the timeout speciﬁed by rel_time **only** if it has obtained ownership of the mutex object". So the function shouldn't end before the timeout unless it has acquired the lock. (However, it can fail to acquire the lock even if the lock is available - but it still can't return in that case until the time has expired). What toolchain are you using?

Comment: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ --version says `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ (crosstool-NG hg+default-9838aecd6340 - tc0003) 4.8.2 20131014 (prerelease)`

Comment: Using gcc 4.8.1 I see the error. Using gcc 6.3.0 I do not see it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little bump-up for those who come late. And many thanks for help!

Got quite same behavior (only in std::shared_timed_mutex). After some digging found out that both `try_lock_for()` and `try_lock_until()` fail immediately if same thread **already has** exclusive lock on mutex, basically saving time on testing broken code.

Tested with gcc-9, gcc-10, clang-10 and clang-12.

Did NOT tested other possible combinations like requesting exclusive lock over shared lock or requesting shared lock over any of exclusive/shared locks.

Comment: That is very interesting. It appears that the semantics of the return value for `try_lock_for()` is an answer to the question, "Did I lock the mutex?" That makes a lot of sense from a library implementation standpoint. For the project I was working on when I posted this question, the code may have been making nested calls to `try_lock_for()` in some cases. The assumption was that the semantics of the return value was an answer to the question, "Does this thread have the mutex locked?" Not the same question at all. Thanks for sharing your discovery!

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear: they **FAIL** PREMATURELY (return false), not succeed.
So they more likely answer the question "did THIS EXACT CALL locked the mutex?"
I don't know if premature failure can be used as any kind of sign that mutex is already locked by same thread with any bit of reliability. The standard says "they can fail spuriously"... However, the specific IMPLEMENTATION can do so.